# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I opened a new project in expo, installed react-native-snap-carousel.
When I import:

```
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
```

I have an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Module.D:\web\my-project\node_modules\react-native-snap-carousel\src\carousel\Carousel.js
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
npm uninstall react-native-snap-carousel
```

Then

```
npm install
```

Try again

Comment: I have tried several times though still the same problem.
I need this carousel, it is the best carousel I have ever seen

Comment: show me how you are rendering your Carousel in the dom

Comment: Works on Android and iOS, though has the same problem on the web